# intellij cant see import no autoimport

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Hi intellij cant see imports from start.spring.io
Is it because of new version of Intellij and spring 2.2.6

I have everywhere Error:  java: cannot find symbol - all for annotation like spring.boot, persistence etc. Intellij cant find this imports.

Where i can find it manually if its necessary to solve this problem?

Idea.log file - https://files.fm/u/3tcr3nz5

Intellij cant see imports and annotations and even some methods
 [image]
[image]

Dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.bykowski</groupId>
    <artifactId>books</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>books</name>
    <description>Aplikacja na Java Mid Dev 2015</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.1.20</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? Does it help if you remove .idea directory and reimport the project?

Comment: You mean .idea2019.3? in user catalogue

Comment: No, .idea in the project root.

Comment: No it didnt help. Still No libraries found for javax.persistance.and others Last week projects for spring 2.2.5 are still working with imports. start.spring.io changed web and added new version 2.2.6. Does it mean we have to wait for update from both side?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: Your POM isn't picked up as the external model for management. Right click the POM and should be an option to use it/recognoise it as a maven project

Comment: It solved this question Thanks Darren.